# "ERROR 1064", "error in your SQL" when installing phpMyAdmin

Tags: debian, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running a VPS using Debian 10 and I've been trying for a few hours now to install phpmyadmin, I've correctly installed, purged and then reinstalled mysql but every time I get this errort when trying to install phpMyAdmin:

```
mysql said: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL │ syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version │ for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY '*mypassword*'' at line 1 .
```

I've tried different passwords and everything, it always comes up with the same error.

Comment: How are you installing phpMyAdmin? What version are you installing? What mySQL version is it? Is it mySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: Are you putting single quotes around your password? If you then try it without.